# Data Factory v2 add Query to Table Storage with function addmonths()

Tags: azure-table-storage, azure-data-factory

We want to filter the data from a Table Storage since the first day of the last month using the utcnow() function.

For this we are applying a workaround in the first 5 days of the month using the following query: Timestamp ge datetime'@{formatDateTime(adddays(utcnow(),-5),'yyyy-MM-01')).
However this implementation is limited to the trigger until a specific day of the month.

Is there any other way to use a function as addmonths(-1) for this query?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`addMonths` and `addYears` are not supported by ADF so far which is mentioned in my previous case:[Subtract number of days based on provided date parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57043010/subtract-number-of-days-based-on-provided-date-parameter/57049386#57049386)

Provide a trick for you,using substring and math function in dynamic content:

```
@formatDateTime(adddays(utcnow(),mul(add(int(substring(formatDateTime(utcnow(),'yyyy-MM-dd'),8,2)),1),-1)),'yyyy-MM-01')
```

For example, utcnow is `7/17/2019....`, the result calculated by above expression is :

[image]

My idea is minus days+1 based on the now date. Please do a try.

Comment: Nice idea with simple logic, really helps to answer my question, Thanks!

Comment: @Praetorian1995 Glad to hear that.