# Subtract number of days based on provided date parameter

Tags: c#, azure, azure-data-factory

I created a pipeline in data factory and I want to retrieve data from a source for the current month and for the previous month. When I run the pipeline I give the needed parameter named ExtractDate. The format is MM/DD/YYYY . 
For the current month I used the following expression in 'Set Variable' activity:

```
@replace(item().Query,'EXTRACTDATE',formatDateTime(variables('ExtractDate'), 'yyyyMM'))
```

And for the previous month I tried:

```
@adddays(variables('ExtractDate'),-28)
```

The problem appears when the user will set when running the pipeline the date 07/31/2019 for example. Then the previous month will still be July. And if I increase the number to 31, then there is a possibility that the user will introduce 03/01/2019 and from March it will skip the month of February.

I tried to think of a solution, but unfortunately there is no 'addmonths' available in data factory.

Any ideas please?...I've spent 2 days on this issue..

Comment: So getting current month works OK, but you are having trouble with calculating previous month ?
Maybe you could use 
    formatDateTime(variables('ExtractDate'), 'dd')
to get day of month, and then use this value in adddays.

Comment: I'm still curious, does your original way of getting current month work or not ?

Comment: Yes, I use it to replace the EXTRACTDATE from an sql query, but I only need yyyyMM. I am still using this logic for the current month. For the previous month I did something like this : @if( equals(variables('SubstringMonth'),'01'), 
concat(string(sub(int(variables('SubstringYear')),1)),'12'), 
concat(variables('SubstringYear'),string(if(or(equals(sub(int(variables('SubstringMonth')),1),11),equals(sub(int(variables('SubstringMonth')),1),10)), 
sub(int(variables('SubstringMonth')),1) , 
concat('0',string(sub(int(variables('SubstringMonth')),1) )))) ))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`addMonths` and `addYears` are not supported by ADF so far.Please vote up this [thread](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory/suggestions/37471768-adfv2-date-function-need-addmonths-and-addyears) to push the progress.

My trick is use combination of [bulit-in functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions) in ADF. Please see my test:

This month is very simple:

```
@concat(substring('07/16/2019',6,4),substring('07/16/2019',0,2))
```

output:

[image]

Last month is little complex.It should check if it is the first month of the year.

```
@if(equals(substring('07/16/2019',0,2),'01'), 
concat(
string(sub(
int(substring('07/16/2019',6,4)),1)),
'12'),
string(sub(
int(concat(substring('07/16/2019',6,4),
substring('07/16/2019',0,2))),1)
)
)
```

if the input param is 01/16/2019,then the output looks like:

[image]

My test is based on the static value,please replace it with your variable.

---

Just for summarize:

The final working dynamic content should be like as below:

```
@if( equals(variables('SubstringMonth'),'01'), 
concat(string(sub(int(variables('SubstringYear')),1)),'12'), 
concat(variables('SubstringYear'),string(if(or(equals(sub(int(variables('SubstringMonth')),1),11),equals(sub(int(variables('SubstringMonth')),1),10)), 
sub(int(variables('SubstringMonth')),1) , 
concat('0',string(sub(int(variables('SubstringMonth')),1) )))) ))
```

Comment: Hi! I tried something like what you did. First I saved the month from the given parameter and the year and then I combined them like this and it works:               
        @if(
 equals(variables('SubstringMonth'),'01'),
 concat(string(sub(int(variables('SubstringYear')),1)),'12'),
 concat(variables('SubstringYear'),string(if(or(equals(sub(int(variables('SubstringMonth')),1),11),equals(sub(int(variables('SubstringMonth')),1),10)), sub(int(variables('SubstringMonth')),1) , concat('0',string(sub(int(variables('SubstringMonth')),1) ))))
 ))

Comment: @Mihnea Glad to providing some useful info for you. Hope you don't mind i summarized your final solution in the end of my answer. Would you please mark it as an answer for others' references?Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

For the previous month from today you could use

```
    formatDateTime(AddToTime(utcnow(), -1, 'Month'), 'yyyy-MM-dd')
```